# How to update a database using textfields values in JDBC?

Tags: mysql, sql, javafx, jdbc

I'm trying to update a database in JavaFX using JDBC and Textfields ,
The first textfields, but I keep getting SQL syntax errors.

It's a simple update syntax , but I have to use the textfield.getText() in order to fill up the data.

I tried this as the query I'll execute:

```
UPDATE intervention 
set "+update_textfield2.getText()+" = "+update_textfield3.getText()+"  
WHERE ( Numdemande ="+update_textfield.getText()+"
```

To explain the code above : set the database field the user entered (update_textfield2) as the value the user entered (update_textfield3) where the "Numdemande" number is x  (update_textfield)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and include the full exception stacktrace you get. Also, please learn about prepared statements and parameters. Your current code is fundamentally unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Its just a school project ^^ I'll add the error I get

Comment: a) Use `PreparedStatement` b) depending on the column type you need to treat the input differently: `INT` does not need to be quoted, but you need to add quotes for `VARCHAR`. c) having the user type in the column name seems suboptimal. It would be much more user-friendly to allow the user to select the column using a `ComboBox`. This would also allow you to preload data about the column types allowing you to treat different types properly.

Comment: "Its just a school project" - All the more reason to learn how to perform the task correctly and show that to your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is unsafe, as explained in the comments, I'll answer on the assumption that your class has not yet covered SQL injection attacks.

As for your SQL statement itself, there are several problems.

- First of all, you are using double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'`. It is unclear which dialect of SQL you are using, but most, if not all, require single quotes when passing through Strings like this.
- Secondly, you are wrapping your calls to the `textField.getText()`
  methods in quotes, meaning you're telling SQL to use that text
  literally.
- You have not added a closing parentheses (`)`) at the end of your `WHERE` clause. The parentheses in this case, however, are not necessary.

In essence, you're trying to pass the following statement to SQL:

```
UPDATE intervention
set +update_textfield2.getText()+ = '+update_textfield3.getText()+'
WHERE ( Numdemande = '+update_textfield.getText()+'
```

Unless you have a field called `+update_textfield2.getText()+` in your table, this statement will fail.

The following `String` would produce the correct statement:

```
String statement = "UPDATE intervention " +
                   "SET " + update_textfield2.getText() + " = " + update_textfield3.getText() +
                   "WHERE Numdemande = " + update_textfield.getText() + ";";
```

> **Side Note:** Please learn the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and stick to them. In your code, you've used [Snake Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) when naming your `TextField`, but should be using [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case#Computer_programming) instead. An appropriate name for your `TextField` might be something like this instead: `updateTextField1`